# Mixpanel ios integration identifier

Tags: ios7, mixpanel

I've already integrated Mixpanel with my ios app and now I need to monitor the users data that's why I've cheched Mixpanel manual to see how this can be achieved. here is what i have so far:

```
[Mixpanel sharedInstanceWithToken:MIXPANEL_TOKEN];
    NSString *uuid = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;
    [[Mixpanel sharedInstance] identify:uuid];
```

The problem is that I'm always getting the following error in my console but I don't know why!!!

```
<Mixpanel: 0xe17ccb0> decide check api error: distinct_id, no user found
```

Anyone has any input on this?

Note that I've checked the value of the uuid variable, it is not nil.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has any kind of onboarding, then when the user signs up, you need to call alias with a unique identifier for your user (like the email or your database unique id). When the user signs in, instead, you need to call identify with that same unique identifier.
Be sure to also call the reset method when your user signs out.